# Typescript convert dictionary list to array dictionary with correct infered type

Tags: typescript

I want a situation like this:

```js
const before = [
  { id: 1, name: 'apple' },
  { id: 2, name: 'banana' },
  { id: 3, name: 'melon' },
]
```

to

```js
const after = {
  id: [1, 2, 3],
  name: ['apple', 'banana', 'melon']
}
```

So, I wrote the logic as below.

```js
const unzip = (arr) => {
  if (!arr) return {};
  return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    Object.keys(cur).forEach(key => {
      acc[key] = [...(acc[key] ?? []), cur[key]];
    });
    return acc;
  }, {});
};
```

Then the type should be guessed like this: But it is not.

```js
const after = unzip(before);
after // <- It is infered to be 'any'.
```

The above "after" should be typed as follows.

```js
after // { id: number[], name: string[] }
```

How should I use Generic?

Comment: TypeScript isn't going to synthesize generic call signatures for you; you need to annotate them yourself.  And the implementation is beyond the compiler's ability to verify as safe so you will need assertions.  Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0AdGW) is what I'd suggest.  If that works for you I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Your code helped expand my knowledge. thank you! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really just taking each element and making the values into arrays:

```
type Unzip<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K][];
};
```

And then we use generics to infer and "store" the type of each element, returning the unzipped version:

```
const unzip = <T>(arr: T[]): Unzip<T> => {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgUwGYgE4JgXhgbQFAwwDeMAlgCYBcMAjADQxgCGAtgtQORMAO3ANgg4wAvnQLEyVGACYGzNpzhNmzIaPEkK1AMxzW7GBzZ9wasQF0A3HjyhIsJkigJUWYuK256MhtvNjCeQMcLl4BDgYOJRUmCMNjU3M8YWs8KABPbgwAVTAAL1JuAB4AFQA+NyJxHABpMjAYAGsEdJAkGBLzahLa8xwrZNS7aBgAV3zCt1KygAomVFRu-oBKalyC4vKsCqrCUnaZgEJ51GWYdChR1AaiYRgmCBh1wunrQgurhpOAOnRyUeACBmc2AwAYwCuZ0wO3EhAA8nAAFYIYBQb7NdIQGYQ07fFCoACiTGAAAsZhjtu5CNSYAB6WkAASgEAAtKQAOZgNAIWHU4nAHAY8xuHDfMUggVCmAAfmluHMy3BV0FLXMAxpwmWb2pH2u91B2tExE1hAeTwmmzK1hSNnGGxmiHxCGW3woljptMYoxYiFQ-Tw9JpQepAD1pUA)